# jQuery, loop through each matching selector, if height less than X apply class

Tags: jquery, foreach

Curious about what I'm doing wrong with this setup, on all aspects. My goal is to loop through every .grid-block on the site, determine which are 58px high or less, and for those that are, add a class .truncate-text to that element's h1 tag.

My HTML (greatly simplified):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-block">
            <h1>Block Title</h1>
            <p>Random length excerpt text.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-block">
            <h1>Block Title</h1>
            <p>Random length excerpt text.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-block">
            <h1>Block Title</h1>
            <p>Random length excerpt text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JQuery I'm trying:

```
$('body').hover(function(){ 
    $('.grid-block').each(function( index ) {
        var gridheight = $(this).height();
        if ( gridheight <= 58 ) {
            $('h1', this).addClass('truncate-text');
        }
    });
});
```

Firstly, I'd love to know how to do this without needing to do the whole "body hover" thing. And then to get the rest to work as outlined.

Still new to the whole JS / JQuery thing.

Comment: What is the purpose of the hover?  Do you want this to happen when the page loads?

Comment: Yes @ntgCleaner, I want it to happen when the page loads and am not sure how to do that / do anything in jQuery without some sort of trigger like .hover or .click, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Check my answer below.  To do anything when the page loads, instead of `$('.example').hover(function(){...}` you would just use `$(document).ready(function(){...}` This fires anything inside of the ready function when the page is loaded.  You can also look into `.load()`

Comment: `.load()` doesn't bind a load event anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting this into a function, so you can make this happen on whatever trigger you want:

```
function addClass() {
    $('.grid-block').each(function(i){
        var expHeight = 58;            
        var gridHeight = $(this).height();
        if(gridHeight <= expHeight){
            $(this).find('h1').addClass('truncate-text');
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can call this whenever.  For example, if you want it to happen on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addClass();
});
```

or in a timed event:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    addClass();
}, 1000);
```

As Kevin B mentioned below - I should have said when the document is ready - if you want it to fire when the page LOADS, it would be

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    addClass();
});
```

Comment: little bit of a wording issue, *"if you want it to happen on page load:"* should be *"if you want it to happen on document ready:"* Though, since he's testing height, you may actually want to wait for page load. `$(window).on("load",...)`

Comment: Good point Kevin.  I guess I always default to doc.ready.  I'll change the above

Comment: Perfect @ntgCleaner, thanks for helping me solve my problem and learn a whole new way of doing things in jQuery at the same time.